# Redirecting Standard Output from a Process (msxsl.exe) to a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, process, redirectstandardoutput

I am writing a command line application in VB.NET. This application is calling another one, msxsl.exe, to run an XSL transform. I am using the Process class to do this:

```
Dim process = New Process()
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msxsl.exe"
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "base.xml test.xsl -o styled.xml"
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
process.Start()
```

This part works great. What I want it to be able to display the output from this process to the console of my application. I have read several posts explaining this method, but it does not seem to work in this case. The output is an empty string.

```
Dim output As String = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
process.WaitForExit()
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

I have verified that if I run the msxsl executable on its own (i.e. running "msxsl.exe base.xml test.xsl -o styled.xml"), it displays output on the command line. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I should note that the msxsl process is currently failing due to a malformed XML file. It is displaying this error message:

> Error occurred while executing stylesheet 'test.xsl'.
>   
>   Code:   0x800c0006
>   
>   The system cannot locate the object specified.

This is exactly the type of thing I want displayed in the console of my application (or, eventually, a log file.)

Comment: Curious: Why aren't you using the built-in XSLT capabilities of .NET (a.k.a. [XsltCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)?

Comment: Tomalak, I did not know there was a class that did this. Thanks for the tip. I'll see if I can get it working this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because this isn't standard output it is `StandardError` you will want to redirect `StandardError` like so `Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True` and then read that into a string.

`Dim ErrorString As String = Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: That is exactly right. Such an easy thing to overlook. Thanks for the answer.